# How to disable Pear caching?

Tags: php, pear

We've been experiencing problems with the Pear cache and these problems are affecting our Puppet agents.

Here's what I mean:

```
$ ls -al /tmp/pear/cache/ | wc -l
211
```

How does one disable pear (php extension management) caching on CentOS?

Comment: Pear caching? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I'm not sure it's disableable. Run `pear clear-cache` when necessary.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well, some of his coworkers have been bringing pears from the communal fruit bowl back to their desks; not to eat, just to have. And he wants to put an end to this deplorable- and, frankly, odd- trend. I have dealt with this exact issue myself, and it was handled by RFID-tagging the pears.